# MS VB 2008: Font Settings Practice

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I am currently practicing some simple codes in VB 2008 in my office and apparently this isn't what I expected. So Im doing currently somethings where I have 3 groups of options: `Font Color`, `Size`, and `Style`. The `Font Color` contains the basic Rainbow colors. The `Size` contains `10-50` sizes by `10's`. And for the `Style` are the basics, `Italic`, `Bold` and `Underline`.

And here is the codes for it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub rbRed_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbRed.CheckedChanged
        txt1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbOrange_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbOrange.CheckedChanged
        txt1.ForeColor = Color.Orange
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbYellow_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbYellow.CheckedChanged
        txt1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbGreen_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbGreen.CheckedChanged
        txt1.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbBlue_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbBlue.CheckedChanged
        txt1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbIndigo_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbIndigo.CheckedChanged
        txt1.ForeColor = Color.Indigo
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbViolet_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbViolet.CheckedChanged
        txt1.ForeColor = Color.Violet
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize10_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbSize10.CheckedChanged
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 10, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize20_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbSize20.CheckedChanged
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 20, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize30_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbSize30.CheckedChanged
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 30, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize40_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbSize40.CheckedChanged
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 40, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize50_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbSize50.CheckedChanged
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 50, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize60_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 60, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize70_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 70, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize80_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 80, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize90_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 90, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbSize100_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 100, txt1.Font.Style)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, FontStyle.Italic)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, FontStyle.Bold)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
        txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, FontStyle.Underline)
    End Sub
End Class
```

My problem is that whenever I choose the `Font Style` the revert back to their original text size. I know it is something to do with the codes inside the `Check Boxes`. How can I make them the same size every time I pick an option in the `Font Style`? And how to make them mixed up at the same time(***SAMPLE***)? This must be very simple to you guys but I need a little bit of your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need a little helper function that can turn a style on or off on an existing font:

```
Private Function ChangeFontStyle(fnt As Font, style As FontStyle, enable As Boolean) As Font
    Dim newstyle = fnt.Style
    If enable Then
        newstyle = newstyle Or style
    Else
        newstyle = newstyle And (Not style)
    End If
    Return New Font(fnt, newstyle)
End Function
```

Now you can write:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    txt1.Font = ChangeFontStyle(txt1.Font, FontStyle.Italic, CheckBox1.Checked)
End Sub
```

Repeat for the other two, now using FontStyle.Bold and FontStyle.Underline

The only thing that's a bit tricky to understand in this code is the use of the And/Or/Not operators.  It is the standard way to turn a bit on or off.  It can also work on an Enum type if the type has the `<Flags>` attribute.  Like FontStyle does.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now my problem is with the reset button. My original txt1 font is Arial, Regular, 8, and White. How do I revert it to it's original form. Do I do it like: `txt1.Font = New Font(txt1.Font.Name, 8, FontStyle.Regular)` ? How do I place the color and font type in?